# Distinction between $O(D\times D)$ and $O(D)\times O(D)$

Tags: group-theory

I want to know the relation between $O(D\times D)$ and $O(D)\times O(D)$. 
And its difference feature for global and local symmetries.

And further generalized to any other groups like $SU(D, D)$, $Sp(D,D)$ and so one.

---

detail explanation for notation  : 
Here $O(D)$ is a orthogonal group of $R^D$. 
Thus $O(D\times D)$ is a orthogonal group of $R^D \times R^D$.

Comment: By $O(D\times D)$ I assume you mean the orthogonal group associated to $\Bbb R^{D^2}$?

Comment: @arctictern, what i mean is $O(D)$ is a rotation group for $R^D$. Thus $O(D\times D)$ is rotation group for $R^D \times R^D$.

Comment: What does $R^D$ denote? I think I understand the kind of question you're asking, but I still don't understand all the notation.

Comment: @phy_math But $D\times D=D^2$ so $O(D\times D)$ is the rotation group of both $\Bbb R^D\times \Bbb R^D$ *and* $\Bbb R^{D^2}$? That doesn't make sense.